# ASP.NET MVC complex model retrieving on the server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Let's say I have model with property:

```
public List<string> Subscribers { get; set; }
```

I am rendering markup like that to receive such list on the server on form submit:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Subscribers[0]" value="SomeSubscriber" />
<input type="hidden" name="Subscribers[1]" value="SomeSubscriber" />
<input type="hidden" name="Subscribers[2]" value="SomeSubscriber" />
```

What if subscriber is a type with Name and ID properties. How should markup look like to get the whole list of subscribers back on form submit?

The challenge is to render markup aproppriately and without use of any editorFor templates

Comment: Use Editor templates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483715/in-mvc4-how-to-save-multiple-row-edits-at-once/13484000#13484000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be :

```
<input type="hidden" name="Subscribers[0].Name" value="SomeSubscriber" />
<input type="hidden" name="Subscribers[0].ID" value="SomeSubscriber" />
<input type="hidden" name="Subscribers[1].Name" value="SomeSubscriber" />
<input type="hidden" name="Subscribers[1].ID" value="SomeSubscriber" />
<input type="hidden" name="Subscribers[2].Name" value="SomeSubscriber" />
<input type="hidden" name="Subscribers[2].ID" value="SomeSubscriber" />
```