# How manage order(sequence) of cookie items in asp.net mvc?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, sequence

I'm working on asp.net mvc5 project . I have a page for show `cart items`, and used cookie for save items . But I have a problem with  `order of cart items` , when I changed number of cart items , the order(sequence) changed . I don't want it I think it's not good . I know it's because of cookie but I don't know how fix it . Could  anyone help me please?

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {
alert("aleeeert");
$(".textCountProduct").change(function () {
    var count = $(this).val();
    var id = $(this).attr("productid");
    alert(count);
    alert(id);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Goods/AddToCart",
        data: { Id: id, Count: count },
        type: "Post",
        dataType: "Json",
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.Success) {
                alert(result.Html);
                $("#CartItems").html(result.Html);
            }
            eval(result.Script);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error....");
        }
    });
  });
});
```

**Good Cotroller**

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddToCart (int Id , int Count)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("NishtmanCart_" + Id.ToString()))
        {
            //Edit cookie
            var cookie = new HttpCookie("NishtmanCart_" + Id.ToString(), (Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["NishtmanCart_" + Id.ToString()].Value) + 1).ToString());
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
            cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);

        }
        else
        {
            //Add new cookie
            var cookie = new HttpCookie("NishtmanCart_" + Id.ToString(), Count.ToString());
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
            cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
            List<HttpCookie> lst = new List<HttpCookie>();
            for (int i = 0; i < Request.Cookies.Count; i++ )
            {
                lst.Add(Request.Cookies[i]);
            }

            bool isGet = Request.HttpMethod == "GET";
            int CartCount = lst.Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("NishtmanCart_") && p.HttpOnly != isGet).Count();
            return Json(new MyJsonData()
            {
                Success = true,
                Script = MessageBox.Show("Good added suucessfully", MessageType.Success).Script,

                Html = "Cart Items (" + CartCount.ToString() + ")"
            }
                );
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            return Json(new MyJsonData()
            {
                Success = false,
                Script = "alert('Good didn't add');",
                Html = ""
            }
                );
        }
    }
```

There is number of cart items in textbox that saved in cookie , when I changed this number , sequence changed . How I prevent this ?
[image]

Comment: I can't quite follow what the issue is here?

Comment: Sorry , that's because my English is not good . I updated my post @AdamTuliper-MSFT

Comment: @shimaamini if you work on online shopping , I offer to you see this open source Project , It can give you some ideas  : http://www.cart42.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is totally unnecessary. You are using [HttpPost] which means it won't be a GET method.

```
 bool isGet = Request.HttpMethod == "GET"
```

Also your HTML above doesn't match your output. We'd need to see  what makes up MyJsonOutput for Html = "Cart Items (" + CartCount.ToString() + ")"

Without seeing that what I'm guessing here is you:
1. Change the qty and submit it.
2. Your AddToCart method checks if the Id is there and then updates the response cookies.I'm assuming this then sends a set-cookie request to the browser and changes your order.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Request.Cookies.Count; i++ )
{
    lst.Add(Request.Cookies[i]);
}
```

To something like this that sorts the keys

```
foreach (var cookie in Response.Cookies.AllKeys.OrderBy(o => o))
{
    lst.Add(Request.Cookies[cookie]);
}
```

With that said you may want to rethink this approach and not use cookies but instead just post the form each time and parse the data - ex
[In MVC4, how to save multiple row edits at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483715/in-mvc4-how-to-save-multiple-row-edits-at-once)
and
[Posting serialized form data AND additional data to MVC controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766348/posting-serialized-form-data-and-additional-data-to-mvc-controller)
in those cases you are using AJAX to send all the data to the server, bind it into a nice model and work with it.